# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Error while copying content to a stream'

Tags: c#, asp.net

```cs
Uri uri = new(PostUrl);

// Convert stream to Multipart form content to send with the request
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName }
};

// creating the Http request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri) { Content = content };

// Sending the Http request
result = await _client.SendAsync(request); // Getting error on this line
```

I am reading a file to a stream and then send this stream to a Web API. When this file is of larger size (I tried 30 Mbs) the above error shows with 2 inner exceptions.

> SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

> IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

There are no such errors for smaller files (~5 Mbs).

Can anyone tell me what is the solution for this?

Comment: Show us some actual code, then we can help.

Comment: Post the actual code and actual *full* exception text. Streams don't have maximum sizes. *HTTP Requests* do, to prevent Denial-of-Service attacks.

Comment: The server has a max limit set.  Most likely you do not have permission to change the max.  Are you using HTTP 1.0 (stream mode) or HTTP 1.1 (chunk mode).  Chunk mode the max limit may be larger.

Comment: All web servers have request and file upload limits. Which server are you using? The IIS default for *files* is 28.6MB since IIS 7 though, which was released in 2009. 4MB was the default in IIS 6, released in 2003 and only used on Windows Server 2003. *Both* versions are long out of support

Comment: Are you sure the *remote server* accepts file larger than 5MB ? The `host` in this error is the server you're calling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using latest IIS version which allows only 28.4 Mbs. That is the issue here. Thanks for the help

Comment: Not "only". That's the default. I repeat, *all* servers have a maximum request size, to prevent malware from crashing the server by eg posting an infinite series of bytes. You can increase the maximum in all servers through a configuration setting